# Removing duplicate rows from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id     lat                long     speed      date          address
 1    22.92138131   72.44103313     3.96 km/h     2011-09-26  National, Gujarat, India
 2    22.92138145   72.44103413     13.96 km/h     2011-09-26  National, Gujarat, India
 3    22.92138134   72.44103423     15.96 km/h     2011-09-26  National, Gujarat, India
 4    22.92138454   72.44103233     13.96 km/h     2011-09-26  10t ring Rd, Nehru Nagar
 5    22.92138354   72.44102533     13.96 km/h     2011-09-26  Anandnagar Rd, Ahmedabad
 6    22.92138484   72.44103293     19.96 km/h     2011-09-26  Anandnagar Rd, Ahmedabad
```

I want to write a query such that my result looks like this:

```
id     lat                long     speed      date          address
 1    22.92138131   72.44103313     3.96 km/h     2011-09-26  National, Gujarat, India
 4    22.92138454   72.44103233     13.96 km/h     2011-09-26  10t ring Rd, Nehru Nagar
 5    22.92138354   72.44102533     13.96 km/h     2011-09-26  Anandnagar Rd, Ahmedabad
```

I want to remove duplicate rows according to the address.

Comment: Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Where an address is duplicated, which row do you wish to return in the resultset? the first by ID?

Comment: id 2 in not looking duplicate to any other rows.. why you want to remove this also..

Comment: is Ian Nelson right ??..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you wish to return the rows with the smallest ID values:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
TABLENAME T INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID FROM TableName 
    GROUP BY Address
) SUB ON T.ID = SUB.ID
```

Answer (score 9):

To check what you are going to delete:

```
SELECT distinct t1.*
  FROM yourtable as t1
  join yourtable as t2
 WHERE t1.address = t2.address
   and t1.id < t2.id
```

If you are happy with that:

```
DELETE t1
  FROM yourtable as t1
  join yourtable as t2
 WHERE t1.address = t2.address
   and t1.id < t2.id
```

This way you keep the record with the max value on id column

Comment: what if I need to keep lower id ?

Comment: Just change `t1.id < t2.id` by `t1.id > t2.id`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care which of the rows you keep

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE KEY 'address' (`address`);
```

The 'IGNORE' is important, that means to silently ignore duplicate data. (ie ignores it when inserting into the 'new version' of the table.)

May want to remove the index afterwoods

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP KEY 'address';
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to create duplicate/temporary table with same field what your current table have.

Then execute below SQL

First clear temporary table :

```
DELETE FROM `#TMP_TABLE#`;
```

Insert record in temporary table as per your expectation.

```
INSERT INTO `#TMP_TABLE#`
SELECT T . *
FROM #TABLE# T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN( ID ) AS ID
    FROM #TABLE#
    GROUP BY address
    ) SUB ON T.id = SUB.id
```

Truncate main table

```
DELETE FROM `#TABLE#`;
```

Copy Data from temporary table

```
INSERT INTO #TABLE# SELECT * FROM  `#TMP_TABLE#`
```

Comment: Are you sure is not possible to do by one query? Check my answer, am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidEG, yes it is possible. you genius. your solution is perfect one

Comment: @maulik.patel, you can use above logic in more complex condition

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table_name tb where id not in 
   (select min(id) from table_name tb1 group by address)
```

I assumed that you want to remove rows having address duplicacy and want to keep minimum id's row in your table

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do this Easily by Doing these 3 easy steps and therefore 3 SQL statements:

Step 1: Move the non duplicates (unique tuples) into a temporary table
CREATE TABLE new_table as
SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1 GROUP BY [column to remove duplicates by];

Step 2: delete delete the old table
We no longer need the table with all the duplicate entries, so drop it!
DROP TABLE old_table;

Step 3: rename the new_table to the name of the old_table
RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table;

For Another Way You Can go to the Bellow Link... Its is Also a good Way... Difficult but with less statements
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html