# insert array into database syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, syntax-error

I'm parsing article links from a friend's basketball website using [DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).  I want to store these values in my database but I'm getting a syntax error Here's the code:

```
<?php
include_once ('connect_to_mysql.php');
    include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://basket-planet.com/ru/');
    $main = $html->find('div[class=mainBlock]', 0);
    $items = array();
        foreach ($main->find('a') as $m){
            $items[] = "$m->plaintext, $m->href";
        }
    //print_r($items);
    $reverse = array_reverse($items);
    print_r($reverse);

    $sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO basket_news (article, link) VALUES ".(implode(',', $reverse))."") or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

This is the output from the reverse array (sorry, it's in a nother language):

```
Array (
  [0] => 07:43 Видео. Дэвид Стерн и арбитры вручают "Лейкерс" победу над "Миннесотой" (1) , /ru/news/9234
  [1] => 07:51 "Чикаго" прервал победную серию "Майами" на отметке 27 (0) , /ru/news/9235
  [2] => 15:02 Кабмин выделил 200 млн грн на подготовку к Евробаскету (0) , /ru/news/9243
  [3] => 20:42 Евролига: ЦСКА ломает мадридский «Реал» (0) , /ru/news/9246
  [4] => 21:45 «Уникаха» побеждает в Стамбуле и молится на «Бамберг» (0) , /ru/news/9248 )
```

And here's the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'07:43 Видео. Дэвид Стерн и ' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Please advise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is not delimited with quotes and not escaped in your code. The Values string should contained by `(` and `)`
So the right way if you use mysql:

```
  $items[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string($m->plaintext)."','".
                  mysql_real_escape_string($m->href)."')";
```

And as the other commenters said, you should try out `mysqli`, or `PDO` in php. The query building is easier and safer than `mysql_*` functions. (And `mysql_*` functions will be deprecated in the next version of PHP)

Comment: Ok, this worked but I got a whole bunch of weird characters in my articles column because the data was in Ukrainian...is there something I need to change for the article column?  I tried UTF-8bin but that didn't work.  Using XAMPP

Comment: You should do after conenct to mysql server:
`mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")`, and set all field in yor database with `utf8_general_ci` collation. And your PHP code, and the source where you get data should be encoded with `utf-8`
And in phpmyadmin (at the 'home page'), set the connection to `utf8` too. To see the data correct.

Comment: One more quick question...I'm having trouble putting in LIMIT 1 into the query.
$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO basket_news (article, link) VALUES ".(implode(',', $reverse))."") or die (mysql_error());
Gives me an error...why?

Comment: Into this query ? You could use `LIMIT` only with `SELECT` query, If you want to limit the inserted rows you should `break` the `foreach` loop if a counter reaches the maximum number of insertions what you want to insert in a query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582508/removing-duplicate-rows-from-a-table, here is a way (in this topic the table scheme is different, but this could help you) to delete duplicated rows from your table after insertion.

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
foreach ($main->find('a') as $m)
{
  $items[] = "'$m->plaintext', '$m->href'";
}
```

And

```
"INSERT INTO basket_news (article, link) VALUES (" . implode('), (', $reverse) . ")"
```

Also, ensure you escape your input (or ideally use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)).