# Delete double rows when columns have identical entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, delete-row, sql-delete

I have a database table (test_table) with an auto-increment column (id) and I want to delete all double (or more) entries when 3 specific columns (A, B, C) have identical entries.

```
    id    column_A    column_B    column_C
------------------------------------------------
    1     ooo         aaa         uuu
    2     ooo         aaa         uuu
    3     ttt         ppp         uuu
    4     ooo         aaa         uuu
    5     iii         kkk         ccc
```

In this example, the rows with id **2** and **4** should be deleted after executing the *DELETE* query.

Regards.

Comment: Are you saying that the first response is always the correct one that should remain? If this is always the case, can you make column a your "primary key" which won't allow dupes by nature? Not a fix but a best practice...

Comment: @Silvertiger: I'm cleaning up an existing database actually. It is not important which auto-increment key left, important is only that the doubled entries are beeing removed and one row of them stays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE `id` NOT IN ( SELECT * FROM (
                                SELECT MIN(`id`) 
                                FROM tbl
                                GROUP BY `column_A`
                                       , `column_B`
                                       , `column_C` 
                              ) x
              )
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad6dd6/2)

Comment: @lickmycode : because you can't use permanent tables in WHERE clause in the `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` queries, so `x` here is to represent it as  a temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join in delete query, subquery in join will join the rows which are duplicate and condition `t.id > tt.id` will keep minimum records with id and other duplicates will be deleted

```
delete t.* from t
join (
select * from t 
group by `column_A`, `column_B`, `column_C`
having count(*) > 1
) tt 
  on(t.`column_A` = tt.`column_A`
          AND t.`column_B` = tt.`column_B`
          AND t.`column_C` = tt.`column_C` 
         AND t.id > tt.id)
```

I have added one more copy of 5th row to test it

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3d53/1)

Comment: With this query I am getting an SQL Error `#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`. Using InnoDB Tables. Does this query takes more resources than the query provided by Notulysses?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick possibility I borrowed this from https://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-delete-duplicate-rows-in-78638.S.218942398 :

> Step 1: Move the non duplicates (unique tuples) into a temporary table
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE new_table AS
> SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1 GROUP BY [COLUMN TO remove duplicates BY];
> ```
>
> Step 2: delete the old table
>
> ```
> DROP TABLE old_table;
> ```
>
> Step 3: rename the new_table to the name of the old_table
>
> ```
> RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table;
> ```

Then you can edit the new table to have column A be the primary key where no further dupes will occur.

Comment: It looks like that Richa Tayal person in that LinkedIn link actually got her answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7582706/456814.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE x
  FROM t x
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT column_a
            , column_b
            , column_c
            , MIN(id) min_id
         FROM t
        GROUP 
           BY column_a
            , column_b
            , column_c
     ) y
    ON y.column_a = x.column_a
   AND y.column_b = x.column_b
   AND y.column_c = x.column_c
   AND y.min_id = x.id
 WHERE y.min_id IS NULL
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1b679/1